# ¿Qué se debe hacer con las preguntas que exponen código comprometedor?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Respecto a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5944/asociaciones-con-anotaciones-en-mybatis), el usuario tiene una inquietud que es absolutamente válida y se acoge a los tipos de preguntas que se esperan en SO en español. Para darle contexto a la misma, el usuario expone código que, de acuerdo a mi opinión, compromete parte de la infraestructura de base de datos de una empresa privada colombiana (Asobancaria), entidad que agrupa buena parte de las entidades financieras del país. Respecto a esto tengo varias inquietudes:

1. ¿Es correcto exponer de esta forma el código? (sin él no habría suficiente información para responder)
2. Una pregunta puede exponer de forma clara código que, a la luz de los contratos de confidencialidad que las empresas privadas mantienen con sus desarrolladores, puede acarrearle problemas volviéndolos públicos. ¿Se debería permitir esto? ¿Debería existir algún tipo de discreción por parte de quien pregunta para evitar al máximo la exposición de detalles?
3. ¿Qué discusión se ha dado en SO en inglés sobre este tema?

**Actualización**

Considero que la pregunta es comprometedora por cuanto expone parte del esquema de base de datos de la empresa, lo cuál se puede prestar para que personas malintencionadas realicen ataques de inyección SQL a través de la página web de la compañía.

Comment: no hay evidencia que sea información verdadera... ni se puede evitar que pase y siga pasando, pero mas allá de estos hechos, cualquier moderador del sitio puede borrar una revision de cualquier publicación. Así una posible solución es editar la pregunta/respuesta, cambiando los nombres y valores para enmascarar las entidades reales, y luego poner una bandera al moderador para que elimine la revision "conflictiva".

Answer (score 10):

Creo que esto es perfecto:

Original: [Question is a Copyright Violation? *(¿La pregunta viola el Copyright?)*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261736/question-is-a-copyright-violation).

Trata sobre una pregunta que fue eliminada, pero se ve la edición sugerida que fue rechazada:

- [Python __setattr__ append Key to list [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5161372), que la pregunta en español sería: *El método de Python que establece atributo agrega clave a la lista [duplicada]*.

Traducción de [la respuesta de Mystical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261737):

> No te molestes en reportarla. No es el trabajo de un moderador o incluso el trabajo del sitio para hacer cumplir los acuerdos de terceras partes.
>
> Si alguien quiere retirar algo del sitio, tienen que presentar una solicitud de *DMCA*.
>
> Moderadores, así como la mayoría de los usuarios y empleados *StackExchange* no son abogados y no pueden decir la diferencia entre:
>
> - Una violación de derechos de autor real reclamado por el propietario del *Copyright*.
> - Un troll haciendose pasar por un propietario de los derechos de autor. Que intenta quitar algo que no le gusta.
>
> Una solicitud de *DMCA* es la prueba de que una entidad requiere dar de baja contenido del sitio. Véase la respuesta de [Joel Spolsky ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/joel-spolsky), en la pregunta *How does SOPA threaten Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange? (¿Cómo amenaza SOPA a StackOverflow o StackExchange?)*, aquí para más detalles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114007

---

Y de mi cosecha:

Creo que es responsabilidad de cada quien mantener los *secretos industriales* (o como se diga en el país de lector) que les fueron encargados.

Yo he posteado código en *StackOverflow* que es propiedad de diferentes compañias (siendo yo el desarrollador, o dentro de un equipo), pero **traducido** a un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Por ejemplo:

> ¿Porque me da este error en esta linea?
>
> ```java
> list.add(new Cliente("Nombre", "Banco", "#Cuenta", "Saldo" ))
> ```

... a lo siguiente:

> ¿Por qué me da este error en esta línea?
>
> ```java
> list.add(new Foo("a", "b", "c", "d" ))
> ```

Donde no se daña a nadie. Todo está en el fino arte del **MCVE (mínimo completo y verificable)**.

Aclaración final: Creo que el comentario que le dejaste, es la mejor forma de tratar estas situaciones, de esta manera, el usuario puede tomar conciencia del peligro que puede ocasionar su descuido.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo, cambias el nombre de los parámetros, la información sensible y ya puedes tener un ejemplo mínimo y verificable y es muy difícil detectar de donde es ese código.