# ¿Es insuficiente una confesión para que SO elimine un contenido?

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas, eliminación-de-respuestas, licencia-del-código

[Comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2863/que-son-estas-ediciones-de-preguntas?noredirect=1#comment9978_2863) de Alvaro Montoro♦:

> JoseAntonioDuraOlmos En el punto 3 de los términos de uso del SO se
>   indica que el usuario debe tener propiedad o derecho sobre los
>   contenidos publicados y que se comparte bajo licencia Creative
>   Commons. SO (o los moderadores) no tiene poder/conocimiento legal para
>   decidir si algo publicado tiene copyright o no, pero estoy seguro que
>   SO no tendría problema en eliminar contenido si una empresa llegara
>   demostrando que el código de una pregunta/respuesta es propiedad suya.

Esto es preocupante.

Yo siempre animo a usar SO. Pero me encuentro con que si alguien de quien soy responsable publicase código propiedad intelectual de la compañía de forma no autorizada no sería suficiente con que esa misma persona confiese para que SO lo elimine. La compañía tendría que **demostrar** que el código es de su propiedad.

Comprendo que si el usuario A publica y luego llega el usuario B diciendo "¡Que soy el jefe de A y no tiene derecho a publicarlo, borrad eso!" en ese caso se pida a B que demuestre lo que dice.

Pero, ¿cuando es el mismo usuario el que publica y luego confiesa que no tenía derecho a hacerlo? ¿Qué licencia tiene SO en este caso? La licencia de alguien que sabemos con toda certeza que ha mentido. O mintió la primera vez o mintió la segunda.

Que SO esté dispuesto a mantener la publicación de un material de tan dudosa procedencia y que dificulte tanto la protección del derecho de autor que ni siquiera la confesión del infractor es suficiente convertiría el uso del sitio en un riesgo legal. ¿De verdad es esta la política de SO?

Comment: Como comentario: la parte final es una opinión personal mía, desconozco la política actual de SO sobre el tema (aunque buscaré información sobre la misma para intentar responder a esta pregunta).

Comment: Hay un ejemplo de un caso lo que describes? Sería interesante más que nada para ver como ha demostrado el autor que el código era suya..o no....Ademas el comentario que dices que es igual de peligro a otras redes social... yo diría que SO es aún más peligroso ya que nadie necesita ser registrado para ver el contenido...

Comment: Es interesante, pero dejando el lado los derechos de autor, ¿Qué pasaría si alguien edita una pregunta válida, con muchas respuestas y puntos y pone una base de datos con las contraseñas de mucha gente? Luego alguien revierte la edición, pero cualquiera puede ver las revisiones anteriores. En ese caso tendrían que eliminar la pregunta, porque no se puede eliminar o quitar de la vista una revisión específica. De esta manera se perdería todo lo hecho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relacionado con lo tu pregunta, hay otra en Meta en inglés: [How should questions containing proprietary code be handled when OP asks for deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254496/579895). Traduzco lo que considero mas importante:

> Generalmente el código no será eliminado a no ser que tengas una razón irrefutable - y no será eliminada por un moderador ♦ ya que no pueden cambiar el historial de revisiones de un post. La eliminación debe ser realizada por alguien del equipo de Stack Exchange con quienes puedes contactar usando el enlace [contacto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) que puedes encontrar en la parte de abajo de la página.
>
> Básicamente, el OP nunca debería haber incluido código propietario, muchos contratos de trabajo tienen clausulas sobre el tema. Se puede argumentar que alguien tan poco cuidadoso se lo merecía. Le puede haber costado mucho a su compañía ya que dicha publicación puede hacer difícil patentar o proteger dicho código.
>
> Otra razón por la que las solicitudes de eliminado son consideradas con cuidado y raramente concedidas es porque la mayoría provienen de personas que han publicado tareas o deberes escolares y no quieren ser pillados por sus profesores. La gente intentará poner cualquier excusa para que su solicitud sea aceptada.
>
> Asi que,en resumen:
>
> - todas las solicitudes de eliminación son consideradas caso por caso por el equipo de SE (normalmente por el Community Manager responsable de ese sitio)
> - debe existir una razón irrefutable para que se conceda la solicitud
> - los moderadores no tienen el poder para eliminar completamente una pregunta o respuesta
> - la eliminación puede ser bastante injusta para los usuarios que se tomaron el tiempo de proporcionar ayuda

Como se ve, es posible la eliminación de posts en Stack Exchange, pero lógicamente se deben cumplir unas condiciones y seguir unos trámites para conseguirlo. Y los moderadores no tienen el poder de hacerlo, solo los empleados de Stack Exchange están capacitados para hacerlo.

Hay otra opción que si pueden usar los moderadores: redactar las revisiones (algo así como *editar* cada revisión). En este caso, otro moderador deberá aprobar dichas revisiones. Sin embargo, yo creo que los moderadores sólo deberían emplear este "poder" en casos muy muy flagrantes en los que el contenido sea especialmente conflictivo.

<sub>*Referencia [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/346768)*</sub>

En definitiva, como ves si que existen mecanismos para la eliminación de contenido. Pero no se pueden utilizar a la ligera. En el caso que planteas,como podemos saber que la "confesión" es real? Y, en definitiva, la culpa de que dicho contenido haya sido publicado nunca es de Stack Exchange, si no del usuario que no fué suficientemente cuidadoso.

Comment: Gracias, la aceptaré en unos días si no se publica una mejor. La conclusión que saco es que SO es tan peligroso como cualquier otro sitio de internet. No se puede tener más confianza en un empleado que publica en SO que en uno que publica en reddit, menéame o facebook porque si se equivoca el problema es igual de grande que en los otros sitios.

Comment: SO es tan peligroso como cualquier otro sitio de internet. Incluso aunque borremos el contenido de absolutamente todos lados, otros sitios "scrapean" SO y lo guardan en sus bases de datos (como archive.org). Entender que esta es la realidad de internet es fundamental.

Comment: `Hay otra opción que si pueden usar los moderadores: redactar las revisiones (algo así como editar cada revisión). En este caso, otro moderador deberá aprobar dichas revisiones. Sin embargo, yo creo que los moderadores sólo deberían emplear este "poder" en casos muy muy flagrantes en los que el contenido sea especialmente conflictivo.`

Comment: La pregunta se refiere a los derechos de copyright, pero parece que cuando te refieres a la posibilidad de "redactar las ediciones" estuvieras sugiriendo trampear las normas valiéndose de alguna forma de subterfugio técnico para poder aplica censura a lo que, según algún criterio, parezca contendido "especialmente conflictivo". ¿Es así Pikoh? ¿Estás considerando torcer alguna regla para poder aplicar censura?

Comment: @asdasdasd inferir eso de mi respuesta es bien una interpretación interesada  o bien ganas de entrar en polémica. En ambos casos, te equivocas de persona. Por un lado,está bien claro a que me refiero ya que como indicas el contexto de la respuesta se refiere a reclamaciones de copyright. Por otro, la herramienta a la que hago referencia es una opción que provee StackExchange,no yo, con lo que en ningún caso sería _trampear las normas_. Y por último,la excepcionalidad de esa opción viene marcada por el hecho de que otro moderador deba aprobar dicha edición. No se donde lees _censura_ ahi :)

Comment: No fue mi intención herir tu susceptibilidad; mi pregunta fue franca y directa, y te agradezco la aclaración, aunque no explicas en qué casos un moderador podría llegar a atribuirse una función que específicamente no se le otorga, aprovechando tu "otra opción". ¿Puedes dar un ejemplo real o hipotético?

Comment: @asdasdasd lo primero disculpas, es dificil deducir la intención de alguien solo leyendo un texto,y posiblemente interpreté mal tu intención :) En cuanto a tu pregunta, como dije antes ningún moderador puede atribuirse ninguna función. Si tienen esa opción disponible (que fue añadida a posteriori,no te se decir exactamente cuando), es que es una función que si se les ha otorgado. Además,para utilizarla debe estar supervisado por otro moderador,lo que evita un uso indiscriminado. En cuanto a ejemplos, solo se me ocurre algun caso en que puediera haber delito. Es algo totalmente excepcional.

Comment: @asdasdasd de todas maneras, yo solo he informado de una opción que existe para los moderadores. Si te fijas,yo mismo digo en la respuesta que es algo que solo debería utilizarse _en casos muy muy flagrantes_,lo que creo que deja clara mi postura. Pero cuando esa opción se hizo disponible,es porque en Stack Exchange se pensó que era necesaria, es posible que en meta en inglés haya mas información,pero ahora estoy en mi teléfono y me es complicado investigar. Trataré de hacerlo y responderte de todas maneras :)

Comment: Creo que estás profunda y moralmente errado, a no ser que ese otro moderador que mencionas sea juez y ya haya emitido su sentencia. [http://www.enciclopedia-juridica.biz14.com/d/delito/delito.htm] Elimina tu respuesta por favor.

Comment: @asdasdasd veo que mi lectura de intenciones no iba desencaminada. Si te refieres a la frase _pudiera haber delito_,no hace falta ningun juez para ver indicios de delito o sospechar que un contenido es susceptible de serlo. Dicho esto,por supuesto no pienso eliminar nada y por mi parte nada mas que comentar. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

**Si alguien quiere retirar algo del sitio, tienen que presentar una solicitud de DMCA**. No hay vuelta atras

Se pregunto algo parecido anteriormente en [¿Qué se debe hacer con las preguntas que exponen código comprometedor?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/507/2027)

Comment: Esto es cierto en el contexto de esta pregunta que versa sobre derechos de autor. Pero hay que llevar cuidado de no extenderlo al caso general. Sí hay circunstancias en que es posible retirar contenido sin recurrir a solicitudes DMCA incluso por parte de quien no tiene los derechos de autor del contenido a retirar.