# ¿Cómo lidiar con un usuario que quiere esconder el contenido de su pregunta editándola?

Tags: discusión

El día de hoy me he topado con el caso de un usuario nuevo que ha publicado una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/210538/21), obtuvo un par de respuestas, una de ellas marcada como aceptada y ahora está haciendo *vandalismo* sobre su propia pregunta, eliminando el contenido, como se puede ver en las [revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/210538/revisions)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En comentarios aduce *derechos de autor*, cosa que, tratándose de un ejercicio escolar y de que fué decisión de él mismo publicar el código, me parece incorrecta, bueno...

Yo revertí una de sus ediciones, pero lo ha vuelto a hacer. Reporté la pregunta a un moderador y ahora he visto que hay un proceso de votos de cierre de la pregunta en proceso.

Pero, si se cierra la pregunta, se perderían los aportes y el tiempo de quienes se tomaron la molestia de responder, ¿no?

En mi opinión, debieramos preservar esta pregunta, ¿está la comunidad conmigo?

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2922/15301. Básicamente,si el op quiere que su pregunta sea eliminada, debe solicitarlo en el [formulario de contacto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), demostrando irrefutablemente que debe serlo. Por lo general, no será eliminada, así que hiciste bien en revertir las ediciones.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en dejarla abierta, de otra manera el autor se saldría con la suya dos veces, una porque obtuvo lo que quiso al recibir una respuesta y dos porque se eliminará el código que según es de "su autoría" cuando todos sabemos que no. Pero se debería cambiar unos detalles, por ejemplo poner un título descriptivo y un mejor detalle del problema.

Comment: @KacosPro una cosa es cerrar, y otra eliminar. Se puede cerrar la pregunta sin problemas, y sin que se pierda nada. Otra cosa sería eliminarla...

Comment: ¡Tienes razón @Pikoh! Confundí los términos (cómo siempre). Aún así no estoy de acuerdo con el motivo de cierre, ya que en la pregunta si hay un intento de solución de parte del autor

Comment: @KacosPro eso ya es totalmente opinable :) Yo solo recalcaba que se puede cerrar sin que se pierdan las respuestas que ya existen ;)

Comment: En los términos de uso de SO (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), aunque no están traducidos a español, se indica que el contenido publicado en la red de SO, le pertenece a SO.  Una vez que alguien publica su código ha cedido el derecho.

Comment: @Diego, tu enlace conduce a contenido en español, es decir, si está traducido. Un saludo.

Comment: Esa es la versión resumida, ahí hay un link a los términos de uso completos, esos solo están en inglés.

Answer (score 4):

Es cierto que la pregunta como tal debería mantenerse, sin embargo aquí los puntos mas críticos a mi parecer son:

1. Con ayuda de los links de apoyo orientar en su máxima posibilidad a los usuarios nuevos
2. Divulgar entre aquellos y aquellas que aparecen como usuarios nuevos sobre la verdadera finalidad de *SO en español*
3. Reportar los comentarios que sean tendenciosos a los insultos directamente a los moderadores
4. Si la respuesta que se ha aceptado es de calidad, brindar el apoyo como comunidad votando positivo por la misma; esto le dará respaldo a quien dedicó tiempo a ayudar

Aplico a título personal algunos de los puntos para llevarlos a la practica, por que si bien es cierto que se le hicieron todas las observaciones necesarias al OP, también es cierto que la respuesta aceptada no recibió mucho apoyo.

Lo anterior, para que quien otorgó la ayuda comprenda que su aporte es de calidad

Por otro lado si quien ayudó es también un usuario nuevo, brindarle la asesoría correspondiente para que sepa que su aporte se debe mantener y ayuda a enriquecer a la comunidad

Comment: Creo que quienes participamos en los comentarios de alguna manera cumplimos con los puntos que expones. Ahora, ¿crees que es correcto revertir las ediciones del OP que eliminaban la pregunta?. Creo que tu te has dado cuenta también que editó la respuesta para eliminar el contenido, yo voté en contra de esa edición y alguien más, no sé si tu, también lo hizo.

Comment: de hecho si @jachguate se notó nuestra participación de manera intensa y eficaz por decirlo de algún modo; totalmente deacuerdo en revertir las ediciones que el OP hizo, pues dañan el contenido y generan contenido confuso, por mi parte te comprendo y apoyo

Comment: Gracias, @shadow, en este caso el OP se molestó y creo que dijo un par de cosas de más. Me resulta algo cansado la mala actitud, pero bueno, es normal que así sea. Gracias por la respuesta.