# Propuesta de cultura: no dar un emcv a quien pida tarea si no piden ayuda en como modificar su código

Tags: discusión

Ya que hemos visto que llegan muchos a pedir la tarea les comparto una estrategia que estoy usando:

Si preguntan como hacer algo les digo como hacerlo, en vez de darles el código.

Es decir, mi respuesta es:

- un teorema o algoritmo en formato matemático
- un pseudocódigo
- un diagrama de flujo
- un diagrama uml
- una [máquina de estados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221668/validaci%C3%B3n-del-campo-nombre-con-espacios-en-blanco/221676#221676).
- diagrama E-R
- et altri

y agrego las explicaciones pertinentes.

[Aquí les dejo un Ejemplo de teorema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/222110/342).

> Lo hago por las siguientes razones:

- es muy útil para la comunidad saber entender lenguaje matemático y/o académico, ya no digamos entender pseudocódigos, diagramas uml, de flujo, y demás recursos de documentación y diseño de soluciones.
- no siempre que alguien pregunta como hacer algo pide que se lo hagas, algunos tienen demasiado orgullo y tampoco está bien mancillarlo.
- siento muy feo que cuando alguien pide ayuda con cosas de ejercicios que no son tan complejos nadie ayude, pues ya he estado allí, (tengo eso como se llama.. empatía [ insertar meme aquí] ).
- porque me molesta como a algunos ocupar mi expertise para hacer código trivial para beneficio de alguien que percibo inmerito, a pesar de que no siento que detrimente mi capacidad profesional o moral.
- considero que una respuesta así puede llegar a ser útil a usuarios con más experiencia técnica.

Comment: ¿Qué es un EMCV?

Comment: [mcve] o por sus siglas EMCV

Comment: Tiene su lógica, si bien nunca lo había visto usar en castellano. Puedes incorporarlo a [Diccionario de términos técnicos en castellano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3381/83)

Answer (score 13):

Si bien es cierto que la comunidad es para apoyarnos, también es cierto y te lo digo como docente que se le hace mucho daño cuando alguien le llega a dar el resultado de la tarea

¿Por qué?

1. No pasó por un proceso de adaptamiento ni menos de razonamiento
2. Quien le entrega el código encontró la solución de un modo en que probablemente por lo novato de quien pregunta no alcance a comprender
3. No hablaré por otras profesiones, pero igual que en las matemáticas el desarrollo de software no lo vas a aprender mas que practicando
4. Solicitar un avance como **yo mismo se los he comentado** ayuda a saber que han intentado y de ese modo aprender a guiarlos
5. Nada garantiza que aquellos que no muestran ni un mínimo de intento, al momento de recibir la respuesta después se van a dedicar a estudiar o tratar de comprender
6. Algunas veces los alumnos (lo digo por experiencia propia) no hacen mas que entregar el código de alguien mas
7. Si un alumno o alumna no intenta por cuenta propia entonces se volverá a atorar cvuando le dejen un ejercicio con instrucciones distintas

Lo anterior por...

1. No puedes saber como ayudar a alguien sino sabes en que punto esta atorado
2. Solicitar un avance obliga de cierto modo a un estudiante a buscar, indagar, practicar y comenzar a entender que siempre deberá asumir una postura activa
3. Muchas de las preguntas que se publican en la comunidad solo son el enunciado o la foto de la tarea; eso también sirve como evidencia del grado de interés de un persona por aprender

¿Qué propongo?

Si la pregunta va orientada a aprender a programar:

1. dejar enlaces a fuentes de libros
2. enlaces a canales de Youtube sobre canales orientados al respecto

Si el OP pregunta como se hace un programa que haga tal cosa o tenga tal funcionalidad

1. Recomendarle fuentes donde se hable de pilas, colas, ciclos, condicionales, etc

He visto como a veces no se aceptan dichas recomendaciones por que el único fin es obtener el código fuente y eso es malo por.....

1. Si el OP solo obtiene el código fuente de la tarea que solicita no se va a tomar la molestia de comprenderlo... al menos no existe evidencia de ello

Estuvo el caso hace poco donde el usuario @jachuate tuvo que revertir los cambios de un usuario que pidió ayuda para hacer el código en Java de una tarea y después reclamo que era de el y queria que la respuesta se borrara cuando es claro que se beneficio de los usuarios de SO en español

Aquí la evidencia: [¿Cómo lidiar con un usuario que quiere esconder el contenido de su pregunta editándola?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3734/c%C3%B3mo-lidiar-con-un-usuario-que-quiere-esconder-el-contenido-de-su-pregunta-edit)

> Por otro lado es fácil identificar a aquellos y aquellas estudiantes
>   que desean aprender, por que cuando se les hace la observación de
>   mostrar su avance; inmediatamente la modifican

Por ejemplo algunas veces mi discurso lleva **por favor añade lo que lleves, tu avance por mas mínimo que sea**

**OPINIÓN COMO DOCENTE**

1. Un alumno debe desarrollar competencias
2. Un alumno debe aprender a ser autodidacta
3. Un alumno debe aprender a desarrollar capacidades investigativas, de práctica
4. Ayudar a que alguien aprenda es complejo, requiere guiarlo, dejarlo practicar, equivocarse y sobre todo APRENDER A ANALIZAR Y DEDUCIR