# ¿Es correcto que un usuario plantee una pregunta y la elimine al resolverla?

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas

Tengo una duda respecto a cómo proceder en caso que un usuario al cual ya se le ayudó a resolver un problema (lo sé por los comentarios de agradecimiento)  elimine la pregunta.

¿Se reporta o simplemente los usuario son libres de eliminar sus preguntas una vez que son contestadas por otro usuarios?

No adjunto el enlace porque me parece que no está permitido.

Comment: Los usuarios son libres de borrar sus preguntas, aunque no recomendable, 
 especialmente si ya tienen respuestas y pueden servir de ayuda a otros usuarios.

Comment: Y no hay nada malo por compartir el enlace. Si crees que hay un problema con una publicación, puedes compartirlo por aquí o darle a reportar a un moderador (explicando qué es lo que debemos revisar). Un saludo.

Comment: Hay condiciones bajo las que un usuario no puede eliminar su pregunta. Por ejemplo, si tiene alguna respuesta que tenga votos positivos, el sistema no le permite hacerlo. Como te ha comentado @AlvaroMontoro, en caso de duda reporta a moderadores y revisaremos el caso.

Comment: @Pikoh también si hay más de una respuesta.

Comment: @fedorqui efectivamente. Está especificado [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: Si la pregunta fue escrita en el sitio, por mas que haya sido borrada, y salvo que haya sido eliminada del sistema, se puede compartir. Se considera que existe, aunque solo la puedan ver moderadores y usuarios con mas de 10k de reputacion.

Comment: Yo pienso que hay 2 posibilidades dependiendo del tipo de pregunta, si la pregunta es off-topic(por ejemplo un error tipográfico) entonces es válido que se borre la pregunta porque en algun momento la comunidad lo hará, si en cambio la pregunta es on-topic y solo lo elimino para que otros no vean que él hizo la pregunta entonces eso es considerado vandalismo y la solución es que levantes una bandera para que un moderador analice el caso.

Comment: Esto me ha ocurrido vaaaarias veces, y no han sido respuestas sencillas, me he tomado el tiempo de analizar y redactar una solución detallada, y tan pronto la ven, a veces dicen gracias, a veces no, y eliminan la pregunta, como si nada.

Answer (score 4):

Correcto es una palabra muy genérica aquí y poco *objetivable*.

Lo que sí es *posible*: si uno pregunta y [no tiene ninguna respuesta o solo una sin reputación positiva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions), *puede* eliminar la pregunta.

Como correcto, lo es poco en muchos casos y yo creo que es cuanto menos reprobable.

Eso sí, se me ocurren casos donde podría ser válido:

- El problema era apenas una errata tipográfica o algo difícil de reproducir.
- La pregunta difícilmente ayudará a otras personas.

En cualquier caso, creo que la convención social en estos casos sería comentarlo a la gente que ha interactuado con uno en la pregunta. Posteriormente, borrar.

Lo que de ningún modo es válido es borrar "para que no vean que lo he preguntado". En tales casos, reporta la pregunta (u otra del mismo autor) para que los moderadores lo revisen y, seguramente, recuperen la publicación. No queremos vampiros que nos chupen las ideas y luego se vayan :)

Comment: Borrar la pregunta para que otros no vean que se ha preguntado se considera vandalismo. Y cualquier usuario con mas de 10k de reputacion puede ver inclusive las preguntas borradas

Comment: @gbianchi claro, coincido totalmente. Pero creo que sí hay casos en que puede borrarse, como comento en mi respuesta.

Comment: Claro, lo decia por el ultimo parrafo ;)

Answer (score -3):

Hay muchas situaciones posibles en que sería ***correcto***, un ejemplo es cuando el usuario plantea una pregunta que **no debería de haber planteado**, ya sea porque por error compartió **código propietario**, porque el error de su pregunta **no se puede reproducir**(como por ejemplo, digamos que se le olvidó instalar la base de datos y quiere llamarla lo cual no es un problema de programación en sí).

Ahora suponiendo que tenga alguna pregunta totalmente válida, acerca de una herramienta que casi nadie usa y por ello tiene pocas vistas, con una respuesta provista por él o alguien más pero con votos negativos en la pregunta, **es totalmente su desición** si desea borrarla para recuperar los puntos de reputación perdidos, así como es su desición si desea **republicarla** o no.

Suponiendo que no fuera el caso de que tuviera alguna razón importante para borrarla y solamente decidiera borrar algunas de las preguntas que ha hecho al azar que no tengan votos positivos, si el sistema detecta que esto sucede de manera consistente [puede levantar una alerta para los moderadores que pueden proceder a revocarte tus privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Antes de eliminar tus preguntas normalmente el sistema te presenta una notificación informándote de esto mismo con el propósito de **evitar daños a la comunidad** intencionales o no intencionales( como que alguien robe tu contraseña y empiece a borrar tus preguntas ).

[image: alerta de eliminación de preguntas]

Adicionalmente recuerda que los **moderadores oficiales** de la comunidad son omnipotentes, cof, cof, bueno casi, y siempre y cuando se trate de hacer algo en este sitio, así que si ellos lo deciden, pueden **revertir la eliminación de alguna pregunta** y tomar las acciones necesariaspara protegerla contra eliminación intencionada o no.

Si alguna vez te hallaras en la difícil situación de tener que eliminar urgentemente alguna pregunta no dudes en comunicarte con ellos, **son los únicos que pueden eliminar preguntas sin dejar rastro de su existencia**.

---

En mi caso particular he borrado preguntas en las que las respuestas eran erróneas y tenía votos negativos, para republicar la pregunta con mejor redacción.

Hay algunos tipos de preguntas que me gustaría borrar pero desafortunadamente a veces la comunidad es muy influenciable y aunque en la pregunta pones algo como

"¿Existe una alternativa de librería para hacer interfaces gráficas fuera de Swing? que NO sea JavaFX porque no me gusta."

obtienes respuestas con muchos votos que dicen

"hoy por hoy JavaFX es la mejor librería del mundo mundial, deberías de considerar usarla, es más debería gustarte si quieres ser una persona normal"

Así que bueno, te dejo voy a adorar a JavaFX porque SOEs lo dice.

Comment: Lo de _si el sistema detecta que esto sucede de manera consistente puede decidir retirarle algunos privilegios automáticamente como el de eliminación de preguntas_ no es cierto. El sistema puede bloquear a un usuario privándole de la opción de preguntar o responder, pero no quitándole privilegios. Los privilegios dependen de la reputación.

Comment: @fedorqui los privilegios no dependen de la reputación, eso te lo sé decir de primera mano, cuando inicié en SOEn me concedieron el privilegio de responder al ver que mi respuesta en comentarios era buena, y eso a pesar de tener únicamente un punto, de igual manera se pueden retirar los privilegios.

Comment: @Rusian. Insisto, los privilegios dependen de la reputación. Mira [la página de privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) y cómo todo depende de la reputación. Con un punto puedes contestar casi cualquier pregunta, lo que es imposible es que con esa reputación comentaras en publicaciones que no fueran tu propia pregunta o respuestas a ella.

Comment: Como bien comenta @fedorqui, los privilegios son otorgados única y exclusivamente via reputación. Los mods no tenemos ningun poder para otorgar privilegios.

Comment: En cuanto a la eliminación de preguntas, esta perfectamente explicado [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) como ya comenté. Las preguntas solo pueden eliminarse si no tienen respuestas, o si tienen una sola respuesta sin votos a favor. En todos los demás supuestos, no se pueden eliminar.

Comment: Otro tema: _Si alguna vez te hallaras en la difícil situación de tener que eliminar urgentemente alguna pregunta no dudes en comunicarte con ellos._ Los mods no debemos en ningun caso eliminar una pregunta por la petición de un usuario. [Aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2926/) tienes una respuesta que dí en su día a una discusión que se produjo sobre la eliminación de una pregunta que contenía código propietario. Ese es el camino a seguir si se da un caso similar.Tambien puedes leer [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033)

Comment: En SO en realidad no se eliminan las preguntas :-), solo se ocultan para cierta parte de la comunidad, si tienes los privilegios adecuados puedes ver todas las preguntas: *eliminads* y *no eliminadas*.